# How do I create a program that changes the color of a sentence based on sentence length as the user types an input?

Tags: javascript, input

I'm trying to make a code that'll change the color of an output div as the 
 user types in an input. I want the color to change based on sentence length 
 and without the use of a button.

Here's the javascript code I have so far:

```
function highlight() {
    var input = document.getElementById("myInput").value;
    var output = document.getElementById("output").innerHTML = input;
}

var sentence = input.split( /[^\.!\?]+[\.!\?]+/g );
var count = sentence.split(" ").length;
console.log(count);

if (count < 3) {
    output.style.backgroundColor = ("red");
} else if (count < 5) {
    output.style.backgroundColor = ("green");
} else if (count < 15) {
    output.style.backgroundColor = ("blue");
}
```

Comment: What exactly is wrong with the code you posted?

Comment: sentence is an array, an array doesn't have a split method - I take it you see the error in your browsers **developer** tools console

Answer (score 0):

If your trying to make the `hightlight()` function run after each keystroke, use the [oninput](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/GlobalEventHandlers/oninput) attribute

```
<input id="myInput" oninput="highlight()">
```

<strike>Also, `sentence` should be defined like this:</strike>

```
var sentence = input.split(/[^\.!\?]+[\.!\?]+/g)[0];
//                               get first item ^^^
```

---

**UPDATE**

The current behavior of the program is this:

1. The `hightlight` function is called on each keystroke
2. The length of the sentence is determined by the number of words composing it.
3. If the input contains multiple sentences, the length is the *total* number words contained by all the sentences.

Take a look at the snippet below:

```js
function highlight() {
  var input = document.getElementById("myInput").value;
  var output = document.getElementById("output");

  output.innerHTML = input;

  //var sentence = input.split(/[^\.!\?]+[\.!\?]+/g)[0];
  var sentences = input.split(/[.!?]/g);
  var count = 0;
  sentences.forEach(function(sentence) {
    count += sentence.split(' ').length;
  });
 
  console.log(count);

  if (count < 3) {
    output.style.backgroundColor = ("red");
  } else if (count < 5) {
    output.style.backgroundColor = ("green");
  } else if (count < 15) {
    output.style.backgroundColor = ("blue");
  }
}
```

```html
<input id="myInput" oninput="highlight()">
<span id="output"></span>
```

---

**UPDATE #2**

As per the OP's request, the desired behavior has been modified:

1. `highlight()` is called on every keystroke
2. The input text is split into sentences
3. Highlighting is applied independently to each sentence
4. One `<span>` tag is created any styled for each sentence

There are two main changes I made.

1. A `<span>` tag is dynamically created for each sentence with `document.createElement`.
2. Highlighting is applied individually to each `<span>` instead of to a single `<p id="output"></p>` tag.

Snippet:

```js
function highlight() {
  var input = document.getElementById("myInput").value;
  var output = document.getElementById("output");

  output.innerHTML = ""; // clear all output 

  //var sentences = input.split(/[.!?]\s*/g);
  var sentences = input.match(/(.+?(?:[.!?]|$))/g);
  
  console.log(sentences);

  sentences.forEach(function(sentence) {
    sentence = sentence.trim(); // remove leading or trailing whitespace

    if (sentence === "") return; // skip empty sentences

    var count = sentence.split(' ').length;

    var t = document.createElement('span');
    t.className = "sentence";
    t.textContent = sentence;

    if (count < 3) {
      t.style.backgroundColor = "#dd6";
    } else if (count < 5) {
      t.style.backgroundColor = "#5f9";
    } else if (count < 15) {
      t.style.backgroundColor = "#59f";
    }

    output.appendChild(t);
  });
}
```

```css
.sentence {
  margin-right: 4px;
  border-radius: 2px;
  padding: 2px;
}
```

```html
<input id="myInput" oninput="highlight()">
<div id="output">
</div>
```

Comment: There's a problem. The console.log continues to display it as 1 no matter what I type.

Comment: Occasionally it will work, but as I type a period in the input, the output text will turn red and stop working.

Comment: Thank you for the feedback. I did not realize that the regular expression in your question did not behave the way you wanted. I will update my answer so that periods are allowed, but I suggest that you work on that regex on your own until it suits your needs. Feel free to comment if you get stuck, of course.

Comment: Thank you. I will comment on anything in case I need any help.

Comment: Sorry for not being clearer with my earlier comments, my mistake. But what I'm trying to make is something like this: https://i.imgur.com/GMyxkJV.png but with the user able to type their own text into it. I will continue trying to work on my code but if you have anything feel free to let me know.

Comment: I updated my answer again -- how does it work for you?

Comment: Now I was wondering how do I create an option for the user of the page to be able to change the default colors of the sentences, and choose their own colors for the sentence lengths?

Comment: Since this is technically a different question from the original, which has been answered, it would be best to post it as a new question so it can go through the system. That being said, I wont leave you hanging :) . Have a look at the [HTML5 color input](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/input/color)! You can use one of these guys for each sentence range color.

Comment: Thanks, I'll try to get some more help from other people!